# Adminhtml / grid.php - I modified grid by adding another attribute. But the other elements disappear on back-end server(adminhtml)

Tags: adminhtml

I'm facing on the issue i mentioned that title.
Partially i want to add the company attribute in back-end customer grid. So i add the attribute and it's worked well

> However, all of sudden, the **another values from name attribute**
>   disappeared.

And i already checked a sort of factors i've guessed

- about database obviously
- Connection issue from database(like joining table with customer information)
- issue about method used when bringing the **full name**

First of all, the data about name are totally on 'customer_entity_varchar' table and also 'attribute_id' are set on accurately.
And the method for bringing full name,i think, is function **getFullCustomerName** in app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper. Look at below.

```
/**
 * Retrieve full customer name from provided object
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $object
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullCustomerName($object = null)
{
    $name = '';
    if (is_null($object)) {
        $name = $this->getCustomerName();
    } else {
        $config = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');

        if (
            $config->getAttribute('customer', 'prefix')->getIsVisible()
            && (
                $object->getPrefix()
                || $object->getCustomerPrefix()
                )
            ) {
                $name .= ($object->getPrefix() ? $object->getPrefix() : $object->getCustomerPrefix()) . ' ';
        }

        $name .= $object->getFirstname() ? $object->getFirstname() : $object->getCustomerFirstname();

        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'middlename')->getIsVisible()
            && (
                $object->getMiddlename()
                || $object->getCustomerMiddlename()
                )
            ) {
                $name .= ' ' . (
                    $object->getMiddlename()
                    ? $object->getMiddlename()
                    : $object->getCustomerMiddlename()
                );
        }

        $name .= ' ' . (
            $object->getLastname()
            ? $object->getLastname()
            : $object->getCustomerLastname()
        );

        if ($config->getAttribute('customer', 'suffix')->getIsVisible()
            && (
                $object->getSuffix()
                || $object->getCustomerSuffix()
                )
            ) {
                $name .= ' ' . (
                    $object->getSuffix()
                    ? $object->getSuffix()
                    : $object->getCustomerSuffix()
                );
        }
    }
    return $name;
}
```

I think it's not problem for method. because i didn't modify this function.

Lastly, this is my grid.php code in core/Mage/Adminhtml/block/customer

**I think this part has problem such as setting attribute and joining table**
I insert **company attribute** on this file

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
        ->addNameToSelect()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('company')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
        ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

**I couldn't find addNameToSelect()method in my server.** I just searched grep command

And,

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
        'width'     => '50px',
        'index'     => 'entity_id',
        'type'  => 'number',
    ));
    /*$this->addColumn('firstname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('First Name'),
        'index'     => 'firstname'
    ));
    $this->addColumn('lastname', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Last Name'),
        'index'     => 'lastname'
    ));*/


    $this->addColumn('company', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
        'index'     => 'company'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Name'),
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));
```

What do you think of that? 
I can see like this,

[image]

Comment: Follow this linke ! =>   http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156798/magento-1-9-x-i-want-to-join-first-name-and-last-name-in-customer-grid/157915?noredirect=1#comment217687_157915